# Python - Stopping a long running taskq's thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, threadpool

I have a fairly simple program that each task added into the taskq is executing and computing something, say for 30 seconds. This task is 'not' running in some kind of while or for loop.

```
def run(self):
    while not self.stopper.is_set():
        DO_MY_30_SECONDS_WORK(self)
        self.task_done()
```

Now, assuming i have a thread.event and this can check before/after the task is done. But is there a way to tell the already running thread to stop or exit it's execution.

Comment: I had an issue something like your last year and used SIGNALs to handle the problem. You can start another thread with your main thread and start a time counter in helper thread. When counter finishes give signal to main thread and kill it by getting signals in it. You may want to look at [this](https://pymotw.com/2/signal/)

Comment: is your task some python code, or is it another program you run using `subprocess`?

Comment: It's just python code but maybe using Curl calls..

Comment: hey author did you get the answer for that.To stop a running thread if possible where the single line that is not composed of loops gets stop abruptly in between

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to stop your running thread if `DO_MY_30_SECONDS_WORK(self)` is blocking. Well arguably you could set it as `daemon` thread and it'll be abruptly killed when your main program execution finishes, this would cause problems if the thread is actually holding resources (e.g. writing to a file) and is generally not a good idea to finish a thread.

What you could do is re-design `DO_MY_30_SECONDS_WORK(self)` and make it non-blocking, which means cutting the work into small pieces and make it check for  the stop sign in a reasonable interval, so that your thread will be responsive enough to finish itself when you tell it to do so.

Comment: Thanks... Yup, that's what i'm going for. I'm just cutting it into smaller pieces.